# Precompiled symbols not finding custom configuration

Tags: c#, .net

I am using VS2010, C#. I have custom configuration named WCFDebug. I've added this configuraion through Configuration manager. I have also added conditional compilation symbols into my project:

[image]

The problem is when I use code like this:

```
#if WCFDebug
/*My code here*/
#endif
```

program never finds my configuration - neither any other configuration, like Debug:

```
#if Debug
/*This one is also not found*/
#endif
```

What should I do, so program finds my configurations with precompiled symbols?

EDIT:

Of course, I expect my program to find this configuration during debug sessions in run-time mode.

[image]

Comment: I get the feeling that you don't really understand what "configurations" are. A phrase like "program never finds my configuration" doesn't have any meaning. And are you talking about compile-time or runtime? Anyway, to specify which configuration is to be used at compile-time you select it via a drop-down on the Visual Studio toolbar.

Comment: If you want to user your custom configuration, then you have to create your own configuration and pick it up from drop down menu. Of course, I expect to find it during run-time.

Comment: @RenniePet has a point. What do you mean by "find the configuration"? You set an active configuration, then compile for that configuration. If the `WCFDebug` configuration is the active configuration, and that has the `WCFDebug` compilation symbol specified, then the compiler will compile the code within `#if WCFDebug [...] #endif`, otherwise not.

Comment: "Of course, I expect to find it during run-time." That statement makes no sense. Configurations only exist at compile-time.

Comment: Maybe you're confusing Visual Studio build configurations with the .Net application configuration file. They are two completely different things.

Comment: I have a project where those configurations are defined. With precompiled directives like this #if WCFDebug [code] #endif I can find when code is executing in one build configuration or the other. But (I don't know why), this is not working in my application.

Comment: @RenniePet, If I run the applicaiton in debug mode, why is it not finding my pre-defined build configurations ? I am thinking about precompiled directiveds, like this: #if WCFDebug ... I know this is possible, it is not just clear to me, why it's not working in my application.

Answer (score 0):

In Solution Explorer, right click on "Solution ...." ->  Configuration Manager - that's how you select active configuration.

Answer (score 0):

First off, forget my last comment on your question. It is now clear that you are indeed talking about Visual Studio build configurations, not configuration information that might be available via an application configuration file.

But the way you talk about "...  I can find when code is executing in one build configuration or the other." does indicate that your understanding of how Visual Studio build configurations work is quite wrong.

Please take a look at this document:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kkz9kefa.aspx

The important thing to realize is that **build** configurations, as their name implies, **only exist and function at build time**.

You select a build configuration and then you do a build, and then the resulting .exe or .dll file is built according to that build configuration, and that's that. That particular .exe or .dll file is, and always will be, running according to how it was built. It makes no sense to talk about "why is it not finding my pre-defined build configurations".

You can build different .exe files based on different build configurations. This is typical for Debug and Release builds, for example. But they are different .exe files, and it makes no sense to wonder why the .exe file that was built using Release can not find the DEBUG conditional constant.

That's the next thing I think you are misunderstanding. The C# preprocessing directives, like #if, and the conditional compilation symbols, like DEBUG and (in your custom configuration) WCFDebug, also **only exist at build time**.

More information here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed8yd1ha.aspx
and here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691095%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

The #if and #endif statements are acted on **at build time** to either include or exclude the statements in between them. Once the build is done, the resulting .exe file no longer has any knowledge of their existence. It either has the specified code or it doesn't, and that will never change for that particular .exe or .dll file.

Now, why things are not working as you expect is presumably due to your not understanding exactly how these things actually work.

If there really is a problem with something not working that isn't related to a misunderstanding, then the only thing I can suggest is that you take a look in the .csproj files involved and check that the configuration names and the conditional symbols are present as they should be. If your Visual Studio solution has multiple projects then I suppose that could be a problem - that the .csproj files do not all properly contain the same configuration information.

Hope this helps.